# opencv python webcam Videoplace-like interface

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, 3d

I would like to create an interface similar to the Videoplace (Myron Krueger, 1985, https://youtu.be/d4DUIeXSEpk) with Python and the built-in web cam from the Macbook. Is OpenCV, a reasonable framework to use? Should I use background subtraction?

My goal is to use in a primitive 3D gesture interface (low latency) to a text editor.

Comment: The first part of  this question seems a bit off topic (asking for libraries tends to be opinion based), but in my experience, at least for prototyping of computer vision algorithms, OpenCV in Python is a useful tool.

Comment: I will start with OpenCV and ask more specific questions, as they arise.